# blazor mqttnet connection fails due to ws vs wss

Tags: blazor, mqtt, wss, mqttnet

I'm coding an application in blazor using MQTTNET nuget to connect to hivemq (a public free server)

If I connect without `WithTls()` It does work when debugging locally but once I upload to github pages it fails because "a https tried to connect to a ws server, it should connect to wss instead".

If I add the Tls it does not connect: `Unable to connect to the remote server` I tried searching if hivemq has a different address for wss or something but could not find out.

This is the code I'm using, mostly copied from the MQTTNET wiki

```
mqttClientOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                    .WithClientId(ClientID)
                    .WithWebSocketServer("broker.hivemq.com:8000/mqtt")
                    .WithTls() //with Tls it does not connect, but no error is thrown
                    .Build();

var result = await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(mqttClientOptions, CancellationToken.None);
```

Comment: The call is made by the browser, which uses TLS by default. Your own page is served through HTTPS so it *can't* connect to unencrypted pages.

Comment: What you tried to do is serve [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) which is [blocked by browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `.WithTls()` you will also need to change the port number.

From HiveMQ's website:

> ```
> MQTT connection settings 
> Host: broker.hivemq.com 
> TCP Port: 1883
> Websocket Port: 8000 
> TLS TCP Port: 8883 
> TLS Websocket Port: 8884
> ```

- 8000 for plain ws
- 8884 for wss

Comment: It's worth noting that the call is made by the browser, from a GitHub page served through HTTPS. Mixed content like this is blocked by all browsers, even Internet Explorer